# Is it possible to access a member inside the parent class body with CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Is there a way in C++11/14/17 to access a member of the subclass in the parent class when using CRTP?

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    using C = typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::next)(T)>::type;
};

class B : A<B> {
public:
    int next() { ... };
};
```

This should result in `A<B>::C` and `B::C` being `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, I am afraid that is not possible. When `A<B>` is used as the base class, it must be instantiated (since a base class must be complete), but at that point `B` is still an incomplete type and thus its members cannot be accessed inside `A<B>`.